# WebStorm addEventListener autocomplete suggestion

Tags: javascript, webstorm

As title speaks for itself my WebStorm does no suggest any event listeners. What could be the problem?

[image]

Comment: maybe you are missing js snippets plugin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there is no such feature in the IDE, please follow [WEB-45081](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-45081) and linked rickets for updates